# Book writing principles

Tags: book

I wanted to write a book/novel. And I don't how to start.

Every profession has its own principles. I am sure writing has as well. and 
I wanted to know what are they?

**Edit:**
This question is not about improving writing skills. It is more about how doing it in right way.

e.g. In keyboard typing when you ask someone about how one should improve keyboard typing skills, the answer mostly could be "You should type more and more everyday, then you become fast typer" or things like that. This is true, but there is one thing. First of all you should put your fingers in right keys like left forefinger on F and right one on J key. Then  you should learn typing with ten fingers, not two, not four etc. then type without looking at keyboard etc. But when If you start learning typing not in this way later it would be much harder to switch to ten-finger typing method. This is a principle of QWERTY keyboard typing.

I hope there should be some in writing too. It is good to know how to do it in right way. It saves your time, and prevents repeating mistakes those had been made before you.

Comment: No ifs, no buts, no coconuts? This is a super, super broad question and is most likely going to get closed. You would more likely get a better response where you to ask a specific question (and on one thing at a time) around a specific problem you may be facing.

Comment: Hello J Clean, and welcome to Writers SE. It seem your question is a bit broad, right? I suggest you to try and edit it to make it more specific. Like for instance, are you interest in a particular phase of writing, like overcoming the blank-page fear? Or are you asking how to get ideas? Or how to organize and schedule your routine? As it is now, this question is too broad to be accepted by the community, so it would help if you can narrow it down a bit. Eager to start the conversation about this!

Comment: There are a lots of sites/blogs on the subject. Just Google- Novel writing: new to writing and read from the results or search this site about how to write a novel. The best way is to start writing, so you have something you can discuss about.

Comment: I don't think there's a right way or wrong way, just your way. Sure, one needs to have at least a basic grasp of the language he wants to write in, how to structure a sentence, grammar, how to conjugate verbs, adjectives, etc. But if you don't have a flair for storytelling, it wouldn't matter how many degrees you have in that language. So the best way to know is to write. You need engaging characters,a plot, a theme,you need to know how to make it flow, scene breaks, etc. In my case,I learn by trying and reading about the art. Also,even the bestselling authors can't do it right the first time.

Answer (score 4):

Write.

It doesn't matter what. What you did today. What you think will happen next to your favorite characters. What the blue lizard said to the mouse. Anything. The more you write the better you will get.

Comment: Why do so many writers think that theirs is the only profession on the planet where there are no principles to be learned? How to learn surgery: just start cutting people up. The more you murder the better you will get.

Comment: @MarkBaker, given the vagueness of the question, I think Arcanist's answer is good. Also, unlike surgery writing is something very natural that we all learn as kids, and it's called literacy, so when we talk about "creative writing" or generic writing skills, it is fair to start saying that practice is the basics. It's the same as running: you don't win the marathon without techinique, but exercising everyday is still a good starting point :)

Comment: @MarkBaker +1 That's what I meant